# Unable to change the old directory name

Tags: visual-studio, rust, visual-studio-2022

The following is my Rust project information under ***Visual Studio 2022***:

[image]

**`Cargo.toml`**:

```
[workspace]


[package]
name = "my_rust_workspace"
version = "4.0.0-dev"
edition = "2021"
description = "Provides the package"
license = "Apache-2.0"

[dependencies]


[[bin]]
name = "main_executable"
path = "./main.rs"
```

**`main.rs`**:

```
fn main() {
    
    let c1 = 5;
    let c2 = 10;

    let _c3 = c1 + c2;
    let _c4 = 200;
}
```

**tasks.js.jason**

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "cargo build",
      "dependsOn": [
        "cargo build example"
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "cargo build release",
      "dependsOn": [
        "cargo build example release"
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "cargo build example",
      "type": "cargo",
      "command": "build",
      "args": [],
      "problemMatcher": [
        "$rustc"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
      }
    },
    {
      "label": "cargo build example release",
      "type": "cargo",
      "command": "build",
      "args": [
        "--release"
      ],
      "problemMatcher": [
        "$rustc"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "cargo",
      "command": "build",
      "problemMatcher": [
        "$rustc"
      ],
      "group": "build",
      "label": "rust: cargo build"
    },
    {
      "taskLabel": "task-Rust - vs2022 debug",
      "appliesTo": "/",
      "type": "launch"
    }
  ]
}
```

**launch.vs.json**

```
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "defaults": {},
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "native",
      "name": "C:\\git\\Rust - vs2022 debug",
      "project": "",
      "projectTarget": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

I have right-clicked on the `cargo.toml` file and selected it as a startup item.

When I want to debug, I see the following:

[image]

That was actually the previous name of my project directory.

I renamed it into `Rust - vs2022 debug`. However, the old name is still showing up.

Now, I am not finding the location where that old name exists. Hence, I am unable to change the name.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: BTW, you should remove `"debug"` from the folder name entirely - because it'll confuse you when you make non-debug builds. Also, having spaces in paths is going to make things more painful in the long-run - I use `C:\git` as my root too, but I'd never name a project folder "`Rust_workspace - vs2022 debug`" - consider renaming it to `C:\git\me\rustproject1` or similar. Avoiding spaces in paths means you don't need to faff around with double-quotes (and then escaping those double-quotes...) in terminals, command-prompts, and build scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue.

I deleted the file **`slnx.sqlite`** inside the **`C:\git\Rust - vs2022 debug\.vs`** directory.

Now, this error is gone.